# Affirmative statements with negative meaning

Tags: grammar, pronouns, sentence

I was trying to understand indefinite pronouns from this [English Grammar Guide](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/indefinite-pronouns) site.

Everything was going smoothly until I bumped into this paragraph.

> **AFFIRMATIVE STATEMENTS**
>
> In affirmative statements, indefinite pronouns with *some* are used
>   to describe indefinite quantities, those with *every* are used to describe
>   completeness, and those with *no* are used to describe absence. 
>   **Often indefinite pronouns with *no* are used in affirmative statements
>   with negative meanings, but these statements don't use *not***.

I didn't understand the bold part. Specifically, I couldn't grasp the concept behind "affirmative statement with negative meaning".

I am beginner with English grammar, so it would be great if you explain it with clear and simple examples.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What's the context of this question? Do you have any examples? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: In response to being told by a prof that in no case in English would two positives make a negative, one student muttered "Yeah, right."

Comment: I'd just call that sarcasm or irony.

Comment: Look at the examples on the page you linked to: “**No one** is sleeping in my bed.”, “There is **nothing** to eat.”, and “There is **nowhere** as beautiful as Paris.” These are affirmative sentences in the sense that the _verb_ isn’t negated, but they are expressing negative meanings: “There **is not** anybody [sleeping] in my bed.”, “There **isn’t** anything to eat.”, etc.

Comment: It just shows that the author of your grammar book doesn't understand English grammar well enough to explain it. Negation has a distinct effect on quantifiers. And there is no such thing as an "affirmative sentence".

Answer (score 4):

The statement I'm about to use is an example, not an opinion.

Consider the following statement:

> You are stupid.

Grammatically, this is entirely positive and affirmative.  The copula directly links you to a simple, positive (meaning neither comparative nor superlative) adjective.  It expresses your (hypothetically) actual state of being.  It contains nothing resembling a negation.  As far as grammar is concerned, the statement is no different than:

> You are happy.

or

> You are smart.

Of these three grammatically positive statements, is there perhaps one which you wish would not be applied to you?

Answer (score 0):

The examples you seek are on the page you linked to:

- **No one** is sleeping in my bed.
- There is **nothing** to eat.
- There is **nowhere** as beautiful as Paris.

These are affirmative sentences in the sense that the *verb* isn’t negated,
but they are expressing negative meanings:

- There **is not** anybody [sleeping] in my bed.
- There **isn’t** anything to eat.
- etc.

---

I find this concept of “negative meaning” somewhat elusive – see
[Does “positive” mean good and “negative” bad?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/119393).  
The [Merriam-Webster definition of “negative”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negative) includes “marked by absence, withholding, or removal of something positive”
and “lacking positive qualities”, which are broad and (IMHO) subjective – especially since
the [definition of “positive”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/positive)
(“good or useful”) is similarly broad and subjective. 
Consider the following sentences:

1. The balloon is red.
2. The car is fast.
3. The balloon is burst (or *has* burst).
4. The car is totaled (i.e., is totally destroyed or has been totally destroyed).
5. The fridge is empty.
6. The apartment is vacant.
7. I just got fired.
8. My boss is mean.

Which of these have negative meanings?  Probably not #1 and #2. 
But #5 is very close in meaning to “There is **nothing** to eat.”
(“There **isn’t** anything to eat.”)
and #6 is analogous to “**No one** is in my bed.” (There **is not** anybody in my bed.”),
both of which reflect an absence of something positive. 
Ditto for #7 – unless I hate[d] my job and don’t need the wages. 
All of them seem to boil down to a matter of opinion. 
The Three Bears might consider “**No one** is sleeping in my bed.” to be a good thing. :-)